# MQTT : TLS Connection : Diffie-Hellman key exchange

Tags: mqtt

Does MQTT Socket Secure connection uses Diffie-Hellman key exchange between MQTT client and broker? Does it uses secret key exchange between  MQTT entities.

How data is encrypted / decrypted in MQTT over secure connection.

Comment: A TLS connection is established first then MQTT packets transmitted over this (the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718098) mentions TLS but does not dictate its use). So your question appears to be "does TLS use DH", and is probably better suited to a [security focused site](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/41226).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MQTT protocol specifications (i.e. [3.1](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html#connect), [3.1.1](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html), & [5](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html)) rely on the existing [*Transport* Layer Security (i.e. TLS) protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt) for secure communication. In short, MQTT and TLS are orthogonal to each other. MQTT doesn't do any key exchange or encryption/decryption. That's the job of TLS.